# How do you wrap four cards around a centered card?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a homepage with 5 card elements.

I want to have 4 items surrounding the 5th element that is centered.

This is a picture of what I'm trying to do. https://i.stack.imgur.com/89XFL.jpg

I have tried searching but I haven't found an example that talks about breaking the "wrap" text on the next row as it shows in the picture. I just don't know what else to search for.

I tried absolute position but that was NOT what I needed. I tried changing `left: 100px` and such to align the items but they wouldn't even move without the absolute position (I don't understand why). I tried using floats but it just created a mess.

```css
.hp-container {
    background: rgb(139, 174, 250);
    flex: flex;
    justify-content: center
}

/* Left Side */
.home-card-1 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: green;
    Color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
}

.home-card-4 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: rgb(93, 130, 207);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: green;
    Color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
}

/* Right Side */
.home-card-3 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: rgb(231, 126, 126);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(25, 0, 255);
    Color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
}

.home-card-5 {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 550px;
    background: rgb(87, 0, 29);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: green;
    Color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
}


/* Middle */
.home-card-2 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: rgb(122, 177, 165);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(37, 0, 0);
    Color: white;
    text-justify: justify;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hp-container d-flex flex-wrap animated fadeIn">
        
          <div class="home-card-1">
              <div>
                <h2>Explainer Video</h2>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="home-card-2">
              <div>
                <h2>Game Hub Center</h2>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="home-card-3">
              <div>
                <h2>Twitter Feed</h2>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="home-card-4">
              <div>
                <h2>Giveaway</h2>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="home-card-5">
              <div>
                <h2>Gofundme</h2>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: Are you open to utilizing something such as bootstrap here?  Example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css grid system. This example shows the basics but you can modify it and make it work as required

```css
.hp-container {
  background: rgb(139, 174, 250);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

[class^='home-card-'] {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-card-2 {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hp-container d-flex flex-wrap animated fadeIn">
  <div class='col-1'>
    <div class="home-card-1">
      <div>
        <h2>Explainer Video</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-card-4">
      <div>
        <h2>Giveaway</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="home-card-2">
    <div>
      <h2>Game Hub Center</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-3'>
    <div class="home-card-3">
      <div>
        <h2>Twitter Feed</h2>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="home-card-5">
      <div>
        <h2>Gofundme</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `flex`, then you need to `modify your html structure` a little bit. CSS flex works in 1-d only (for 2-d you should use css `grid`). Still, if you want to use flex, you need to modify the html structure in such a manner that there are 3 columns with left containing 2 divs, mid containing 1 div and right containing 2 divs:

```css
.hp-container {
    background: rgb(139, 174, 250);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

/* Left Side */
.home-card-1 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
}

.home-card-4 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: rgb(93, 130, 207);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
}

/* Right Side */
.home-card-3 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: rgb(231, 126, 126);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(25, 0, 255);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
}

.home-card-5 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: rgb(87, 0, 29);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 380px;
}


/* Middle */
.home-card-2 {
    margin: 10px;
    background: rgb(122, 177, 165);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(37, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    text-justify: justify;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hp-container d-flex flex-wrap animated fadeIn">
    <div class="left-wrap">
        <div class="home-card-1">
            <div>
              <h2>Explainer Video</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="home-card-4">
            <div>
              <h2>Giveaway</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="mid-wrap">
      <div class="home-card-2">
        <div>
          <h2>Game Hub Center</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="right-wrap">
        <div class="home-card-3">
            <div>
              <h2>Twitter Feed</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="home-card-5">
            <div>
              <h2>Gofundme</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for css grid, @brk as given a good answer.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex like this:

```css
.hp-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.card{
  color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
.home-card-3{
  height: 420px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hp-container">
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="card home-card-1">
            <div>
                <h2>Explainer Video</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card home-card-2">
            <div>
                <h2>Giveaway</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="card home-card-3">
            <div>
                <h2>Game Hub Center</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col3">
        <div class="card home-card-4">
            <div>
                <h2>Twitter Feed</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card home-card-5">
            <div>
                <h2>Gofundme</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```